# How to properly centre CSS pseudo elements in their base element

Tags: html, css

I created a circle in CSS and I created another circle using pseudo-elements 'after'.
but the created pseudo-element circle is not properly centred in the main circle.

can someone tell me what are the different ways to centre pseudo elements?

Thanks.

```css
.main{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

.first{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgb(202, 202, 202);
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px 1px #e8eef6;
    position: relative;
}

.first::after{
    content: '';
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgb(78, 78, 78);
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
        <div class="first"></div>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already using `flex`, so stick with it:

```css
.first {
  display: flex;
  place-content: center;
  place-items: center;
}
```

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.first {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(202, 202, 202);
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 1px #e8eef6;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  place-content: center;
  place-items: center;
}

.first::after {
  content: '';
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(78, 78, 78);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="first"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use the [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) property and [translate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate) method and you'll also need `top` and `left` properly.

with `top: 50%;` we'll set top position to `50%` and with `left: 50%;` we'll set left position to `50%`

then with `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` we'll change horizontal and vertical directions.

so the below combination is generally used to center alignement with position absolute.

```css
 top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.first {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(202, 202, 202);
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 1px #e8eef6;
  position: relative;
}

.first::after {
  content: '';
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(78, 78, 78);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="first"></div>
</div>
```